# Thread lock clarification

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am a beginer in programing.

When i  execute the code by locking the operation:

```
class ThreadSafe
{
    static List<string> list = new List<string>();
    static object obj=new object();
    static void Main()
    {
        new Thread(AddItems).Start();
        new Thread(AddItems).Start();

        foreach (string str in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Count=" + list.Count.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
    static void AddItems()
    {
        lock (obj)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
             list.Add("Item " + i.ToString());
        }

    }
}
```

even i am reciving,"InvalidOperationException".What would be the code alteration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that your threads are altering the list while it is trying to be read.

```
class ThreadSafe
{
    static List<string> list = new List<string>();
    static object obj=new object();
    static void Main()
    {
        var t1 = new Thread(AddItems);
        var t2 = new Thread(AddItems);

        t1.Start();
        t2.Start();

        t1.Join();
        t2.Join();

        foreach (string str in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Count=" + list.Count.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
    static void AddItems()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
            lock (obj)
            {
                list.Add("Item " + i.ToString());
            }
    }
}
```

The difference being that this code waits for both threads to complete before showing the results.

I also moved the lock around the specific instruction that needs to be locked, so that both threads can run concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

You're enumerating over a collection with `foreach (string str in list)` while modifying it in `AddItems()`. For this code to work property you'll either have to `Thread.Join()` both threads (so that both will finish adding items to a list; I'm not sure, however if `Add` is threadsafe; I bet it's not, so you'll have to account for that by locking on [SyncRoot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356596.aspx)) or use a [ReaderWriterLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock.aspx) to logically separate these operations.

Answer (score 1):

You are looping through the result list before the two AddItems threads have finished populating the list.  So, the foreach complains that the list was updated while it was looping through that list.

Something like this should help:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(0); // Let the other threads get started on the list.
lock(obj) 
{
  foreach (string str in list)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(str);
  }
}
```

Watch out though!  This doesn't guarantee that the second thread will finish it's job before you have read through the list provided by the first thread (assuming the first thread grabs the lock first).

You will need some other mechanism (like John Gietzen's solution) to know when both threads have finished, before reading the results.

Comment: Why the -1?  He is seeking to understand the problem, and this helps to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the debugger. :)

You receive the InvalidOperationException on the foreach.
What happens, is that the foreach is executed while your threads are still running.
Therefore, you're iterating over your list, while items are being added to the list.  So, the contents of the list are changing, and therefore, the foreach throws an exception.

You can avoid this problem by calling 'Join'.

```
        static void Main()
        {
            Thread t1 = new Thread (AddItems);
            Thread t2 =new Thread (AddItems);

            t1.Start (); 
            t2.Start ();

            t1.Join ();
            t2.Join ();

            foreach( string str in list )
            {
                Console.WriteLine (str);
            }
            Console.WriteLine ("Count=" + list.Count.ToString ());
            Console.ReadKey (true);
        }
```

Comment: 3 minutes late. ;) That's almost an exact duplicate of mine.

Comment: Yeah, I've upgraded your answer since you were first.  (You must have posted it while I was still running the example in vs.net).

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the code, which proves lock does nothing.
I expected add2 won't show up until add1 has finished. But add1 and add2 just mingled together.
using System;
using System.Threading;

public static class Example
{

```
public static void Main()
{
    int data= 0;

    Thread t1 = new Thread(()=> add1(ref data));
    Thread t2 = new Thread(() => add2(ref data));
    t1.Start();
    t2.Start();
}

static void add1(ref int x)
{
    object lockthis = new object();
    lock (lockthis)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            x += 1;
            Console.WriteLine("add1 " + x);

        }
    }
}
static void add2(ref int x)
{
    object lockthis = new object();
    lock (lockthis)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            x += 3;
            Console.WriteLine("add2 " + x);

        }
    }
}
```

}